# Can't output variable in change function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

i will get the value on select with change function in jquery. I used a global variable to get the value, but the console.log don't works outside my function:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var formule;

    $('#group_14').on('change', function() {
       formule = this.value;
    }); 

   console.log(formule);
});
```

The console log just works with this code:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var formule;

    $('#group_14').on('change', function() {
       formule = this.value;
       console.log(formule);
    });  
});
```

I want to recover my `formule` variable to use it after in other functions, how can return my variable in all my script?

Comment: This is because the event hasn't happened yet. You need to *always* follow the pattern in your second example.

Comment: the code console.log(formule); runs before change happened to formule variable.

Answer (score 2):

Think about whats going on with the event as the page loads:

In the below snippet, `console.log` is **outside** of the `change` event so will output to console on page load i.e. **before** the event has fired, `formule` is not initialised as anything at that point

```
jQuery(function($){
    var formule;

    $('#group_14').on('change', function() {
       formule = this.value;
    }); 

   //outside of the change event, formule is null or undefined
   //until the event is fired and formule is intialised
   console.log(formule);
});
```

The following snippet will output the value for `formule` **after** `formule` has been initialised by the `change` event

```
jQuery(function($){
    var formule;

    $('#group_14').on('change', function() {
       formule = this.value;

       //formule has been initialised within the scope of the change event 
       //so is no longer null or undefined and can be used elsewhere
       console.log(formule);
    });  
});
```

Comment: Good observation!

Comment: In first example can trigger change also

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so how i can solve the problem? i will create a function after with this variable inside to addition it with other variables